# kohana won't display errors, gives blank page

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.2

I am obviously doing something wrong with a new class/function I am trying because the page won't render at all. All I receive is a blank page if I call this new errorous class/function.

In order to debug it, to see where it bursts, I am trying to enable all error showing stuff but I seem to not doing it right.

I read that I should use `ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);` but I am not sure where to place this code?

How can I solve the white page issue please? I would very much like to see the error causing lines/codes.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of situations where PHP won't send back an error, eg memory related or max execution time. Have you tried checking the web server error logs?

Comment: Thank you. You are/were correct. Apparently it was a memory related issue.

Answer (score 4):

Without any code, it's impossible to tell you what is wrong, but if you question is how to display errors, you can add the following to the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

The first line tells php to display errors on the screen and the second line specifies what errors to display (in this case, all).

Comment: Hello and thank you. I am still getting a white/blank page if I call the error causing function. The function is norvig's spell checker's php implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you put at the start of your controller in the method being called (assuming it's making it that far)

```
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You'll see all errors.  This is good for troubleshooting, but you should learn to use the settings for the kohana version you have for logging and error display